# How to focus in captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection method

Tags: ios, image, camera, avcapturesession

I am trying to take photo on iOS.

I stuck whit taking image from method **captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection**.

I implement that method and it work but my problem is that it take image immediately and don't wait to focus it first.

I really tried to find the answer but I didn't.

I have implement preview video like this:

```
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = cameraImage.frame;
captureVideoPreviewLayer.bounds = cameraImage.bounds;
captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
[cameraImage.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
 device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];


 NSError *error = nil;


if ([session canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080]) {
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
}

[session addInput:input];
stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey,nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

[session startRunning];
```

and on button pressed I have:

```
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
{
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) { break; }
}


[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
     if (exifAttachments)
     {
     }
     else{}


     // TAKE IMAGE


    if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
        [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.f)];
        [device setExposurePointOfInterest:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.f)];

        [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
     UIImage *rotatedImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];

     [session stopRunning];
```

But unfortunately taken picture is not focused.

Can some one help me out.

Marko

Comment: Have anyone idea how to fix this, or at least idea where to look into?

Comment: @Marco - Did you ever get help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look to observe the adjusting focus value and take your photo after it has completed. Firstly I just before I normally attempt to capture an image I check if the device is focussing and add an observer instead if it is:

```
if ([device isAdjustingFocus])
{
    [device addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"adjustingFocus" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil ];
}
else
{
    // You can just take the image if the device isn't adjusting
}
```

Then create a method to observe the value change:

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString: @"adjustingFocus"])
    {
        BOOL adjustingFocus = [ [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] ];
        NSLog(@"Is adjusting focus? %@", adjustingFocus ? @"YES" : @"NO" );

        //
        // If not adjusting focus then call
        // captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection here
        if (adjustingFocus == NO)
        {
            // Remove the observer when we're finished
            [device removeObserver: self forKeyPath: @"adjustingFocus" ];

        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps...